# Retrive total quantity of ordered Items using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to get Quantity of an item that is requested and yet not received.
Process of purchasing and Item is as
Created Purchase Order > Ordered Items saved in `ItemsRequested` table
Created Purchase Invoice > Received Items are in `ReceivedItems` table

Using below query to get Items Requested quantity but the result is wrong. What is logically wrong in query ?

```
select Sum(ItemRequested.Quantity) as OnOrder from ItemRequested
Inner join PurchaseOrders on ItemRequested.PurchaseOrderId = PurchaseOrders.PurchaseOrderId
Inner join PurchaseInvoices on PurchaseInvoices.PurchaseOrderId = PurchaseOrders.PurchaseOrderId
inner join ItemReceived on ItemReceived.PurchaseInvoiceId = PurchaseInvoices.PurchaseInvoiceId
where PurchaseOrders.DateOrdered >'2019-04-15 11:37:26.537' and ItemRequested.ItemId=3439
```

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: share text data not image

Comment: share your table schema and data in text format.

Comment: @DarkRob how to give schema in text format ? you want table structure ?

Comment: If you're consistently getting exactly double what the right answer is, a hackish method for now is to put `/ 2` (divided by 2) after your `SUM()` function

Comment: @MaxVoisard thanks for the suggestion sir ! but accepted answer has worked for me :) thanks all of you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of the items you need is "requested but not yet received". So you have to retrieve the rows that are in `ItemRequested` but absent from `ItemReceived`.
Thus your query should be more like this

```sql
SELECT  SUM(ItemRequested.Quantity) AS OnOrder 
FROM    ItemRequested
        INNER JOIN PurchaseOrders ON ItemRequested.PurchaseOrderId = PurchaseOrders.PurchaseOrderId
WHERE   PurchaseOrders.DateOrdered >'2019-04-15 11:37:26.537' 
AND     ItemRequested.ItemId=3439  
-- Exclude the PO having received items
AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM PurchaseInvoices 
        INNER JOIN ItemReceived ON ItemReceived.PurchaseInvoiceId = PurchaseInvoices.PurchaseInvoiceId
    WHERE PurchaseInvoices.PurchaseOrderId = PurchaseOrders.PurchaseOrderId
)
```

Comment: Thanks  a lot man ! you are genius . Thanks for quick help . Stay blessed :)